# How to connect Google Cloud Functions to an external managed DB (Planetscale)?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to connect my GCP Cloud Functions to Planetscale.
From [what I understand](https://github.com/planetscale/beta/discussions/32), the best way to do this would be utilizing [Connection strings](https://docs.planetscale.com/concepts/connection-strings).
Is it possible? I haven't found any examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do was `npm install mysql2`, then use the Connection String to run queries:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const DATABASE_URL = 'mysql://.....';

const connection = mysql.createConnection(DATABASE_URL);
console.log('Connected to PlanetScale!');
connection.query(`SELECT * from users`, function (err, results, fields) {
    console.log(results);
})
connection.end();
```